# How can I programmatically get the path of "System.Core.dll" using VB.NET?

Tags: .net

Is there is a way to get the path of "System.Core.dll" assembly or any other assembly rather than the executing one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know of a *type* that exists in the assembly, you could use [**`Type.Assembly`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assembly.aspx) to get a reference to the containing assembly. Then it's just a matter of getting its [**`Location`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location.aspx) property.

In this *specific* case, you could do (sorry that this in C#):

```
//The Enumerable class is in System.Core
typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable).Assembly.Location
```

A more general solution for an assembly for which you do not know of a particular contained-type but do know has been loaded into the current AppDomain would be something like (untested):

```
AppDoman.CurrentDomain
        .GetAssemblies()
        .Single(assembly => assembly.GetName().Name == mySimpleName)
        .Location
```

Otherwise, there's no easy solution. You've got to figure out where to *probe* for the assembly of interest.

EDIT: Fully qualified `Enumerable` for clarity.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you and for Code Gray!

Comment: @Cody Gray: Great, thanks. Just wanted to reiterate that I'm talking about `System.Linq.Enumerable` rather than `System.Collections.IEnumerable` (that's in mscorlib). Perhaps I should have chosen a better sample type.